# Angular 6 - ngModel showing object object when binding showing data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a variable called "data" which contains this data:

```
{
id: 1,
date: "2018-03-13T16:18:03",
date_gmt: "2018-03-13T16:18:03",
guid: {},
modified: "2018-05-03T17:25:36",
modified_gmt: "2018-05-03T17:25:36",
slug: "hello-world",
status: "publish",
type: "post",
title: {
rendered: "Hello world!"
},
```

...etc

On my app.component.html, id shows fine when I use:

```
[ngModel]="data?.id"
```

My problem comes when I try to display title.

When I try:

```
[ngModel]="data?.title.rendered"
```

I get: `[object Object]`

But when I use:

```
value="{{data?.title.rendered}}"
```

It display's the title.

How can I  get

`[ngModel]="data?.title.rendered"` to display the title instead of `[object Object]` ?

Comment: how you show them in html? try ```{{data?.title.rendered | json }}```

Comment: I know that works. But I want to use [ngModel] instead

Comment: i want to know where and how you display your data and get the object object result, your html?

Comment: In an input: Like this: <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" [ngModel]="data?.title.rendered">

Comment: It does work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glppwu

Comment: @Vega your demo working fine but where is the problem try to set this  `[ngModel]="data?.title?.rendered"

Comment: I updated the demo with that, still working?

Comment: Strange that it works on your demo and not on mine

Comment: Where is the difference from your code? in the class or in the template?

Comment: In the template

Comment: I see you found the solution. If you are still looking put more relevant code in your post or adapt the demo to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmghlt),

in component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  data = {
    id: 1,
    date: "2018-03-13T16:18:03",
    date_gmt: "2018-03-13T16:18:03",
    guid: {},
    modified: "2018-05-03T17:25:36",
    modified_gmt: "2018-05-03T17:25:36",
    slug: "hello-world",
    status: "publish",
    type: "post",
    title: {
      rendered: "Hello world!"
    }
  }

  myForm:FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            "title": ['', Validators.required]
        });      
    }
}
```

in html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" >  
    <input type="text" class="form-control m-input" formControlName="title" name="title" id="title-field" placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]="data?.title.rendered">
</form>
```